# Aggregating nested fields of varying datatypes in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, types, aggregate

I have an index based on Products and one of the fields declared in the mapping is Attributes. This field is a nested type as it will contain two values - key and value. The problem I have is that the depending on the context of the attribute the datatype of value can vary between an integer and string.

For example:

```
{"attributes":[{"key":"StrEx","value":"Red"},{"key":"IntEx","value":2}]}
```

It seems the datatype for every instance of 'value' within all future nested documents within Attributes is decided based on the first data entered. I need to be able to store it as a integer/long datatype so I can perform range queries.

Any help or alternative ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a mapping like this one, for the `value` field:

```
    "value": {
      "type": "string",
      "fields": {
        "as_number": {
          "type": "integer",
          "ignore_malformed": true
        }
      }
    }
```

Basically, your field is `string` **but** using `fields` you can attempt to format it as a numeric field.

When you want to use `range` queries then use `value.as_number`, for anything else use `value`.